# What does adding the word "silly" to this idiom does?

Tags: idioms-in-context

So, I know about the phrase knock someone's socks off but recently I heard someone say "knocked your *silly* socks off".

What value does the word "silly" add? Are they calling the listener silly? Does it convey the humour in the phrase? Or is it just a filler that emphasizes the meaning?

Comment: Who said this? Are they a native speaker? If so, where from?

Comment: I would guess it was a euphemism for a swear word, i.e. very gentle intensification. But can't be sure without context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To '*knock someone's socks off*' means to impress them greatly. It's clearly figurative, as you couldn't literally 'knock' a sock off.

A lot of humour is subjective and contextual, so it's difficult to say exactly what the effect of adding this word is. On one hand, adding a *descriptive* adjective to describe the word 'sock' could complicate the idiom as the hearer is left wondering if you are referring to their *literal* socks. Do you think that their literal socks are 'silly'? Has the idiom now become literal?

On the other hand, the word 'silly' can be used as a very mild alternative to an *expletive*. While certain expletives / swear words are also technically adjectives/adverbs, they only serve to add emphasis to what is being said. Recognised as such, your sentence makes sense and the idiom is preserved. It might say something about the speaker, that they would choose such a childish word to curse with, and some humour could lie in that.

Comment: English men used to say 'I'll knock your silly head off' or I'll punch your silly face' and I think the implication was that the other person was culpably stupid or foolish. 'Silly socks' has the advantage over just 'socks' of being [affectionately] alliterative.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I'm an English man and I've never said that.

Comment: 'I cannot stand Ronaldo and I could punch his silly face purely on remembering that wink he gave in the 2006 World Cup match' - ' Older women ache to fondle his strong chin, and other guys want to punch his silly face', '“If Wingate wasn't here, I'd punch your silly face like Coker's.” Cedric Hilton shrugged his shoulders and walked away.'